# RavenDb DynamicIndex Stored fields

Tags: .net, nosql, ravendb

I was surprised when noticed RavenDb marks some DynamicIndex fields as Stored. I am curious why it does so and based on what criteria.

**Update.** Index definition screenshot:
[image]

Comment: What does you index looks like?

Comment: @AyendeRahien, I have added index definition screenshot

Comment: That is a UI bug, it isn't actually stored. You can look at that when looking at the http://localhost:8080/indexes/Auth/Cities/ByNameSortByName?definition=yes directly

Comment: @AyendeRahien, so DynamicIndex never contains Stored fields? Please post your comment as answer - I will accept it.